# QGIS imported geotiff rendered as perspective view, how to change to top

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, import

I've created a GeoTiff that should have GPS coordinates in it using AgiSoft.  When I load it into QGIS, it renders the image in a perspective and I want to always see the image from the "top" down.  When I split the GeoTiff into bands, I get a top down view of the raster.

Is this an issue with how I exported the GeoTiff or is there a way to tell QGIS to "view from top" (change the projection?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the GeoTiff is in WGS84 EPSG:4326 with degrees as units. As you may know, degrees of latitude and degrees of longitude have different lengths if you are away from the equator.

What you expect to see is a projected CRS, like Web Mercator EPSG:3857 or the UTM zone of your part of the world. In QGIS, you can set the **project** CRS to change the view using `Project -> Project Properties, CRS tab` and enable on-the-fly-reprojection, without changing the GeoTiff's projection.

Comment: Not 100% sure if the projection I chose is correct, but I ended up enabling WGS 84/ World Mercator, EPSG:3395 seemed to do trick.